# Join in linq query using multiple fields

Tags: c#

I am trying following select query with join using multiple fields in linq,
but compiler is giving me the error on join that :- **the type of one of expression in join clause is incorrect**

```
(from allTeamRoles in GetAllTeamRoles()
                    join includedRoles in _jobManagerClient.GetAllJobRoles().Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
                    on new { allTeamRoles.Id, allTeamRoles.TeamId } equals new { includedRoles.RoleId, includedRoles.TeamId }
                    select allTeamRoles).ToList();
```

Can somebody throw a light on this, what is wrong with this statement, Thanks.

Comment: What are the types of your IDs?  Are they all the same?

Comment: Yes they are all int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Join keys have to have same properties, but in your case left key has `Id,TeamId` properties, and right key has `RoleId,TeamId` properties. So you have to rename either `Id` to `RoleId`, or do the opposite.

```
(from allTeamRoles in GetAllTeamRoles()
 join includedRoles in _jobManagerClient.GetAllJobRoles().Where(x => x.JobId == jobId)
 on new { allTeamRoles.Id, allTeamRoles.TeamId } equals new { Id = includedRoles.RoleId, includedRoles.TeamId }
 select allTeamRoles).ToList();
```

Comment: oh nooo...sometimes we get blind, thanks, that was the problem.